# Is {{#foo}} good for both looping and conditional in Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

I found that in Handlebars, the use of loop:

```
{{#each foo}}  static text or {{bar}} or {{.}}  {{/each}}
```

and conditional:

```
{{#if foo}}    static text or {{bar}} or {{.}}  {{/if}}
```

can both be just replaced by

```
{{#foo}}     static text or {{bar}} or {{.}}    {{/foo}}
```

But I can't find any of that in the [official documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/).  Is that true and does someone know where it might be documented?

Comment: I think it depends on foo object. have you got an example ?

Comment: I don't know of a handlebar.js CDN to use in jsfiddle, so I am using one from can.js: http://jsfiddle.net/5YmdD and http://jsfiddle.net/5YmdD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handlebars.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/) is an extension to the [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) templating language and as such a lot of its logic can be found in Mustache documentation.

If you look under the **sections** definition in [Mustache manual](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), you will see

> Sections render blocks of text one or more times, depending on the
> value of the key in the current context.
>
> A section begins with a pound and ends with a slash. That is,
> `{{#person}}` begins a "person" section while `{{/person}}` ends it.
>
> The behavior of the section is determined by the value of the key.
>
> **False Values or Empty Lists**
> If the person key exists and has a value of false or an empty list,
> the HTML between the pound and slash will not be displayed.
>
> **Non-Empty Lists**
> If the person key exists and has a non-false value, the HTML between
> the pound and slash will be rendered and displayed one or more times.
>
> When the value is a non-empty list, the text in the block will be
> displayed once for each item in the list. The context of the block
> will be set to the current item for each iteration. In this way we can
> loop over collections.
>
> **Non-False Values**
> When the value is non-false but not a list, it will be used as the
> context for a single rendering of the block.